# Performance/Low level meaning of " a(idx) = [] " vs "a = a(~idx)"

Tags: matlab, performance, low-level

As the title says, I wish to know what does Matlab do differently between the two options. For the sake of argument, let's say that matrix `a` and `idx` are sufficiently large to be dealing with memory issues, and define:

- **Case A:** `a(idx) = []`
- **Case B:** `a = a(~idx)`

My intuition says that in Case A performs a value reassignment, which then the CPU needs to deal with indexed copies from original positions to the new ordered ones, while keeping track what is the current "head" of the same matrix, and later trimming the excess memory.

On the other hand, Case B would perform an indexed bulk copy to a newly allocation memory space.

So probably Case A is slower but less memory demanding than Case B. Am I assuming right? I don't know, immediately after writing this I feel like Case B needs to perform Case A first... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer probably depends on the sizes of `a` and `idx`, and perhaps on the Matlab version. Why not just [time](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) the two options yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting, so I decided to take a measure:

I am using Windows (64 bits) version of Matlab R2016a.
CPU: Core i5-3550 at 3.3GHz.
Memory: 8GB DDR3 1333 (Dual channel).

```
len = 100000000; %Number of elements in array (make it large enouth to be outsize of cache memory).
idx = zeros(len, 1, 'logical'); %Fill idx with ones.
idx(1:10:end) = 1; %Put 1 in every 10'th element of idx.

a = ones(len, 1); %Fill arrary a with ones.

disp('Measure: a(idx) = [];')
tic
a(idx) = [];
toc

a = ones(len, 1);
disp(' ');disp('Measure: a = a(~idx);')
tic
a = a(~idx);
toc

disp(' ');disp('Measure: not_idx = ~idx;')
tic
not_idx = ~idx;
toc

a = ones(len, 1);
disp(' ');disp('Measure: a = a(not_idx);')
tic
a = a(not_idx);
toc
```

Result:

```
Measure: a(idx) = [];
Elapsed time is 1.647617 seconds.

Measure: a = a(~idx);
Elapsed time is 0.732233 seconds.

Measure: not_idx = ~idx;
Elapsed time is 0.032649 seconds.

Measure: a = a(not_idx);
Elapsed time is 0.686351 seconds.
```

Conclusions:

1. `a = a(~idx)` is about twice faster than `a(idx) = []`.
2. Total time of `a = a(~idx)` equals sum of `not_idx = ~idx` plus `a = a(not_idx)`
   Matlab is probably calculating `~idx` separately, so it consumes more memory.
   Memory consumption meters only when physical RAM is in full consumption.
   I think it's negligible (`~idx` memory consumption is temporary).
3. Both solutions are not optimized.
   I estimate, fully optimized implementation (in C) to be 10 times faster.